# Is CSP Layout always the first algorithm used by qiskit transpiler to map quantum circuit?

Tags: transpiler, qiskit

I'm using Qiskit [`transpile`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html) with `optimization_level=3`. I was wondering if CSP layout selector is always the first algorithm tried by Qiskit, also if I set as `layout_method='noise_adaptive'` or other methods.

If not, how to force the transpiler to use CSP layout selector? I tried with `layout_method='csp_layout'`, but I get the following exception:

```
qiskit.transpiler.exceptions.TranspilerError: 'Invalid layout method csp_layout.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For Qiskit 0.23 or earlier (qiskit-terra 0.16)

The answer is *yes*, `CSPLayout` will run in optimization level 2 or higher, even if a `layout_method` is provided.

This file constructs the pass manager for optimization level 3:
https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/transpiler/preset_passmanagers/level3.py

Currently, the first choice for layout selector is always `CSPLayout(coupling_map, call_limit=10000, time_limit=60)` and the possible options for `layout_method` (if CSP layout does not find a solution) are `'trivial'`, `'dense'`, `'noise_adaptive'`, and `'sabre'`.

---

#### For Qiskit 0.24 or latter (qiskit-terra 0.17)

With the merge of [PR #5495](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/5495), the answer is *it depends*. `CSPLayout` runs in level 2 and 3. If `layout_method` is provided, then that method will be used.